# Why is animation speed increasing each time the target element is deleted and recreated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, canvas

I've created a jQuery plugin based on somebody else's Chrome experiment that inserts a canvas element into your target element, and draws an interactive starfield in the canvas.

Each time you resize the window, the canvas element is removed and then restored so that its size matches its parent element and everything animates properly; it's responsive.

However, whenever it's restored, the speed of the animation increases. Why does it do this? I thought all the variables (including speed) were reset to their defaults with the this.start() method.

You can see the code (and demo) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/bigsweater/pen/KbCIh); you can also fork it on [Github](https://github.com/bigsweater/jQuery-Canvas-Starfield), though I think the Github version is several commits behind my own.

(Also, this is my first real jQuery plugin, so if you see any issues, by all means, let me know.)

Any clues?

Comment: Maybe the old animation is still on.

Try using `.stop()` before activating a new `animate` function

Comment: There's no .animate() to .stop().

Comment: The idea is the same. Are you calling your `anim()` again and again making everything happen multiple times?

Comment: Could it be that when the window increases from say 100 - 120 , that is a 20% increase therefor a 20% increase in star speed, but when it goes from 120 - 100 . It is calculated as a 16.67% decrease in window size therefor you are back to the same window size but your star speed does not decrease proportionally because of the point of view it is calculating things from?

Comment: Hmm. @Itay Yes, using requestAnimationFrame with a setTimeout fallback. However, when I call cancelAnimationFrame inside the reset() method, there's no difference...

Comment: @Four_lo I don't think that's it; this is using exactly the same math as the original (see link in the Github readme.md), which doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cancelAnimationFrame` *alone* won't necessary stop the animation loop (it turns out).

To be absolute sure you will need to use a *conditional check* as well - a generic example:

```
var isPlaying; /// our condition

function loop() {

    /* funky stuff here */

    If (isPlaying === true)
        requestId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

Then starting it:

```
functiom start() {
    isPlaying = true;
    loop();
}
```

Now when you want to stop the animation you need to do:

```
function stop() {

    isPlaying = false;

    /// kill any request in progress
    if (requestId) cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
}
```

If you don't do this you risk stacking calls to the loop - for example:

If you resize and cAF isn't stopping rAF from re-trigger the loop, the old loop will still run in the background and you will start a new loop on top of that.

That is why you see speed increases as the old and the new loop will both increment the positions before the stars are drawn to screen.

On the third re-size yet another loop is started, and eventually the whole thing will block the browser.

## However

Instead of utilizing start and stop of the loop I would recommend you the following approach:

- Create canvas once
- Start the loop only once
- In this case, a re-factoring of the whole re-size mechanism could be beneficial (for instance, separate needed initializations (width and height of element) from first time initializations that can be re-used later).
- There is no need to re-init the stars for each re-size as you will use the width and height to check their boundaries (canvas will do the clipping).

When resizing you *can* consider using a conditional flags to prevent *render* while re-sizing.

Although generally, a condition to block rendering while canvas changes size is really not necessary due to the single-thread nature of JavaScript and in cases such as this you do boundary check on current element size. Canvas itself will take care of the clipping for you.

And that being said: there should be no need to *re-create* the canvas element each time.

This creates an unnecessary overhead. Simple set new width and height on its properties if canvas is already created:

```
if (typeof canvas === 'undefined')
    canvas = /* only create if it doesn't exist */

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

PS: **[I "hampered" a version with some brute-force-ish implementations](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CLKhn)** of the above. It's far from complete or of high quality but takes out some of the pain for the sake of example to give you a couple of pointers.

Please adopt to suit your needs.

**Update**:

To include more info from the additional comments:

when a new size is set on a canvas element its *context* is reset to default (`fillStyle` becomes transparent, `strokeStyle` black, transform is reset and so on).

This means that all non-default settings must be set again after each new size is set.

Setting a new size may (and typically do) clear the content of the canvas as well so that all pixels becomes transparent black.

Comment: This is the sort of answer that makes SO great. Thanks for helpin' me learn.

Comment: I updated my pen to reflect some changes you suggested (refactoring, especially). I discovered, though, that your code wasn't actually resizing the canvas (though it seems to be doing so in codepen, for some reason), which was a no-go. Resizing the canvas resets the canvas, so whenever I updated its dimensions, I lost all the stars. The new code resets the position of the stars proportionally to the dimensions as they update.

Answer (score 0):

### For anybody struggling with manually updating a `canvas` element's dimensions:

Resizing the `canvas` element results in it discarding anything that's been drawn to it up to the point of the resize.

This script's animation should have *continued* to draw to the canvas after resize, but the only thing that would update was the `fillRect` of the background; the stars disappeared.

The only way to get the stars back after changing the dimensions of the `canvas` element: an extra call to `context.strokeStyle`. I have no idea why; if anybody could shed some light on the matter, I'd be much obliged.

***Edit:*** As per comments below, *everything* in the canvas resets—including stroke and fill style (both default to black, apparently). So as the resize fires, I had to re-define stroke and fill styles.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on this - canvas *do* clear everything on new size (it becomes a brand new bitmap with a reset/new context) incl. styles (stroke -> black which is why you don't see the stars after new size is set). As part of re-factoring you should put style settings etc. in the part that gets called when resized.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks for the info. I did put the style rules into `resizer()` after hours of wondering why the rectangle was resetting, but not the stars, even though the loop was still going; turns out, you can't see black stars on a black field. Meantime, as part of the refactoring, I moved a bunch of public functions into `init()` (as they were logically initializers), and moved the rAF definitions and some vars into the global space; I'm not sure if that's violating any holy rules of Javascript, but the code works! Thanks again.